# How to install Windows 8 apps manually?

Tags: windows-store-app, windows-8-apps

How can I get the .appx file of any application on Windows store to install it manually using Powershell. I also wanna know how to extract the .appx file from installed apps??

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tryed to execute the aspx as a script in powershell?

Usually this would be the case as the type of file is scripted.

if you get any errors like execution policy restricted, change the policy to remotesigned so it will run locally (  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ).

Usually to run a script in powershell you just simply point to the file in the directory or change to the location and point. ( .\UtilityFunctions.ps1 ).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry.. It's not aspx , it's appx.. Windows store app  extension..

Comment: If you kindly tell me how to get the appx file of popular apps on Windows store..  I want the installation files...